# 3rd party Android XML parser?

Tags: android

Would you please tell me about any good third party xml parsing library that can be used in Android

thanks

Comment: Why not just use the SAX parser?

Comment: Check it out... http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/ SAX,XMLpull,DOM

Comment: SAX is great. I just wanted to explore other approaches

Comment: You can use this link that give basic knowledge of DOM and also give advance DOM examples... http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) is just WONDERFUL. You can use SAX or DOM which come in the official SDK, but compared to SimpleXML they are too complex (again: **compared to** Simple XML).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SAX](http://sax.sourceforge.net) or [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/). I believe SAX is a bit faster than JDOM. You can find more information about SAX on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML

Also, here's a link to SAX on Android and class references from android.com: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/sax/package-summary.html